# Mysql select of a documents revisions, with results listed by date and revision history

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to list a document revision list in a table. I want to start from the last revision (highest number the last version) and then get the previous revisions, all this going by **date descending**. I can't solve the problem with the date interval. If the document revision has a different date the result is not correct. **Please notice that docID is not incremental. It's a random number and might be lower in the latest docs. That's why I can't order by docID**

```
CREATE TABLE docs (
  `date` DATE,
  `docID` varchar (11),
  `revision` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO `docs` (`date`, `docID`, `revision`)
VALUES
    ('2019-12-14', '7684230519', 3),
    ('2019-12-14', '7684230519', 2),
    ('2019-12-14', '7684230519', 1),
    ('2019-12-13', '5327968140', 11),
    ('2019-12-13', '3742596081', 1),
    ('2019-12-12', '9475081326', 1),
    ('2019-12-12', '5327968140', 10),
    ('2019-12-12', '5327968140', 9),
    ('2019-12-12', '5327968140', 8),
    ('2019-12-12', '5327968140', 7),
    ('2019-12-12', '5327968140', 6),
    ('2019-12-12', '5327968140', 5),
    ('2019-12-12', '5327968140', 4),
    ('2019-12-12', '5327968140', 3),
    ('2019-12-12', '4736850129', 2),
    ('2019-12-12', '4736850129', 1),
    ('2019-12-12', '2946175380', 2),
    ('2019-12-12', '2946175380', 1),
    ('2019-12-12', '2736489051', 2),
    ('2019-12-12', '2736489051', 1);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hid6sNp6wLeG7PkW3EkpbF/1

See docID 5327968140 date is not listed in order of revision.

```
select * FROM docs
order by date desc,docID desc,revision desc

2019-12-13  5327968140  11
2019-12-13  3742596081  1
2019-12-12  9475081326  1
2019-12-12  5327968140  10
2019-12-12  5327968140  9
2019-12-12  5327968140  8
2019-12-12  5327968140  7
2019-12-12  5327968140  6
2019-12-12  5327968140  5
2019-12-12  5327968140  4
2019-12-12  5327968140  3
```

I need it like this

```
2019-12-13  5327968140  11
2019-12-12  5327968140  10
2019-12-12  5327968140  9
2019-12-12  5327968140  8
2019-12-12  5327968140  7
2019-12-12  5327968140  6
2019-12-12  5327968140  5
2019-12-12  5327968140  4
2019-12-12  5327968140  3
2019-12-13  3742596081  1
2019-12-12  9475081326  1
```

Comment: Your expected results do not contain all the rows from your fiddle sample data. Post the correct expected results.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your sample seems you need

```
select * 
FROM docs
order by docID desc,rev desc, date desc
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. Btw docID is not incremental, It's a random ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order on the docID first and then date and rev

```
SELECT * FROM docs
ORDER BY docID DESC, date DESC, rev DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately docID cannot be ordered as it's not incremental :(

Comment: That's not a problem, here what we want is simply group the entries by docID and then order them by date and rev. If you don't order by docID first, you'll never have what you want

Comment: If I order by docID the dates come wrong. Forget the id in my example and try with different docID where the latest document has not a higher number:

Comment: If you order only by docID, then yes the output is going to be wrong but here you order by doc (id, name or whatever you've got to identify the same document), date and then revision. Actually the answer of Idz is better because ordering on rev and not on the date should be enough.

Comment: Please see this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hid6sNp6wLeG7PkW3EkpbF/1 As you see date come out wrong. Thank you.

Comment: That's because its ordered by date first and not docID. Here is a fiddle with my query https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vKFbzhseuMuiGjpBVbFmrZ/1

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
select * FROM docs
order by docID desc,revision desc;
```

returns

```
| date                | docID    | revision |
| ------------------- | -------- | -------- |
| 2019-10-10 00:00:00 | 24422134 | 3        |
| 2019-10-09 00:00:00 | 24422134 | 2        |
| 2019-10-09 00:00:00 | 24422134 | 1        |
| 2019-10-10 00:00:00 | 23222223 | 2        |
| 2019-10-10 00:00:00 | 23222223 | 1        |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hid6sNp6wLeG7PkW3EkpbF/0)

Based on the updated question, it seems like the `revision` has the highest sort priority, then within equal revisions the `docID` needs ascending order.

This can be achieved with the corresponding statement:

```
select * FROM docs
order by revision desc, docID asc
```

Comment: Not working because docID is not an incremental number (random id), that's why I need a different approach :(

Comment: It returns the desired output, so it is working on the data you outlined in the question. What exactly is not working?

Comment: It's not ordering the dates as expected. In my example the docID is higher on the higher date but as it's a random number it can be anything. If you reverse the numbers of docID you will see.

Comment: Seems like the requirements don't match what has been described in the question then.

Comment: I have updated my data. Please see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hid6sNp6wLeG7PkW3EkpbF/1 (see docID 5327968140)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all revisions for each document grouped together with latest revision first, and documents ordered by their latest revision's date:

```
select docs.*
from (
    select docID, max(date) max_date
    from docs
    group by docID
) docs_max_date
join docs using (docID)
order by max_date desc, docID, revision desc
```

To only search for a date range, add it in the subselect (for efficiency) and in the main select where condition:

```
select docs.*
from (
    select docID, max(date) max_date
    from docs
    where date between ? and ?
    group by docID
) docs_max_date
join docs using (docID)
where max_date between ? and ?
order by max_date desc, docID, revision desc
```

Change `where max_date` to `where date` if you want only revisions in the date range, not documents whose latest revision is in the date range.

Comment: How do I select by date range with this? where docs_max_date.date ?

Comment: do you want to select entire documents, based on their max date?  or select only some revisions based on the revision's date?

Comment: @Robert upated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `docID`s with the highest `revision`s first:

```
select d.* 
from docs d inner join (
  select docID, max(date) date, max(revision) revision
  from docs
  group by docID
) t on t.docID = d.docID
order by t.date desc, t.revision desc, d.docID, d.revision desc;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hid6sNp6wLeG7PkW3EkpbF/4) (for your sample data in the fiddle).
Results:

```
| date       | docID      | revision |
| ---------- | ---------- | -------- |
| 2019-12-14 | 7684230519 | 3        |
| 2019-12-14 | 7684230519 | 2        |
| 2019-12-14 | 7684230519 | 1        |
| 2019-12-13 | 5327968140 | 11       |
| 2019-12-12 | 5327968140 | 10       |
| 2019-12-12 | 5327968140 | 9        |
| 2019-12-12 | 5327968140 | 8        |
| 2019-12-12 | 5327968140 | 7        |
| 2019-12-12 | 5327968140 | 6        |
| 2019-12-12 | 5327968140 | 5        |
| 2019-12-12 | 5327968140 | 4        |
| 2019-12-12 | 5327968140 | 3        |
| 2019-12-13 | 3742596081 | 1        |
| 2019-12-12 | 2736489051 | 2        |
| 2019-12-12 | 2736489051 | 1        |
| 2019-12-12 | 2946175380 | 2        |
| 2019-12-12 | 2946175380 | 1        |
| 2019-12-12 | 4736850129 | 2        |
| 2019-12-12 | 4736850129 | 1        |
| 2019-12-12 | 9475081326 | 1        |
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I need 2019-12-14 to come up first (14,13,12). Can you fix this?

Comment: That's perfect. Great. :)))) How can I select a specific date range searching only the last revision?

Comment: This is a new requirement and for this you have to post a new question where you will explain clearly what you want and provide sample data and the expected results. If this answer solved your current problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.